# Is System.Security.Cryptography namespace supported by the Portable Class Library

Tags: .net, c, silverlight, cryptography, portable-class-library

I am converting an existing multi-target Silverlight/.NET project to a Portable Class Library project in order to reduce the number of projects that are required to support multiple Microsoft platforms.

I have an error in one class that is using the System.Security.Cryptography namespace

> The type or namespace name 'Cryptography' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This namespace is available in Silverlight and I am wondering why the Portable Class Library does not support it?

One reason could be that this behaviour is by design: any cryptography related code should not be present in a client side API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No unfortunately, Portable Library does not support Crypto. However, we've added support for it in [PclContrib](http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Great stuff. Looks like PclContrib contains the missing bits for the Portable Class Library v1.

Answer (score 4):

I would suspect it does not support it. Members on classes in that Namespace are marked with an image:

> You can find which members are supported by the Portable Class Library project in the reference topics for the .NET Framework Class Library. In the members table for a class, the following Portable Class Library icon appears next to supported members. [image: Portable Class Library]

That image is lacking in every class I examined in the documentation.

> This namespace is available in Silverlight and I am wondering why the Portable Class Library does not support it?

I can't say for sure; but it does appear to be lacking under XNA for the XBox 360 platform. Even then, I believe your conclusion is correct - it isn't an API that is very popular on a front end. Then underlying code is also extremely non-portable. A large portion of the Crypto namespace is accomplished by P/Invoking down to the operating system. I suspect they could make it portable as they did with Silverlight; but that may just not have been on their radar just yet.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use [PclCrypto](https://nuget.org/packages/pclcrypto). It's the simplest to use and invokes platform crypto rather than trying to implement it itself, which means less security risk and faster performance.

Answer (score 1):

"You can find which members are supported by the Portable Class Library project in the reference topics for the .NET Framework Class Library. In the members table for a class, the following Portable Class Library icon appears next to supported members. "

I would recommend using the object browser, as I have found examples of classes that the MSDN indicates are supported in the PCL, but are missing from the framework. Such an example is Lazy

(as of 2011-9-11)