# Any equivalent of DataProtection in Portable Class Library (Xamarin / C#)

Tags: c#, xamarin

We have a Web Api that receives input strings in GET requests in an encrypted format provided by Microsoft ProtectedData class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata(v=vs.110).aspx

We want to employ this web api in a Xamarin mobile app, so we need to encrypt strings and pass along. The encryption should be compatible with what protected data class provides in Xamarin's PCL code. How can I achieve this goal while ProtectedData class is not accessible in PCL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is System.Security.Cryptography namespace supported by the Portable Class Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794446/is-system-security-cryptography-namespace-supported-by-the-portable-class-librar)

Comment: For PCL-based support you can look at 3rd-party support, i.e. `PclContrib` or use the Microsoft-based System.Security.Cryptography.XXXX namespace Nugets within your native app projects.